# Resources for 800-171 compliance with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: security

Coming from the Red Hat world, automating SCAP benchmarks for 800-171 compliance is a snap because the profile is baked into the SSG.

NIST 800-171 is a very common control set in the US, and will become even more prevalent as CMMC is put into place.

Is Canonical working on SCAP benchmarks for US controls (ie, not ANSSI, which are the only controls currently benchmarked in ComplianceAsCode)?

Example 800-171 profile on the Github project for OpenSCAP's security guide content: https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/blob/master/rhel7/profiles/cui.profile

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I found it helpful https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs